# Laplace Transform on Beam (w/ Loads)

Tags: laplace-transform

(Sorry about my english I'm a South American student)

The deflection of a fixed beam is zero at $x=0$ and $x=L$ on its boundaries. The beam resists a distributed load of $Wo$ per unit length. The equation is:

$$\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^4}=\frac{W_{0}}{EI}$$

$$0 < x < L$$
Where $Wo$, $E$, and $I$ are constants

$y(0) = y''(0) = y(L) = y''(L) = 0$

Solve using Laplace Transform

Comment: You need to do a little work. Here is one approach, take the Laplace transform to get a solution with unknowns $y'(0), y'''(0)$. Use this and the values of $y(L), y''(L)$ to determine $y'(0), y'''(0)$.

Comment: You can perform a 'direct' integration. You don't need Laplace$\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Take Laplace Transform of the equation, but perform this with respect to x (where normally, it is performed with respect to time, t):

$$ \mathcal{L} \left[ \frac{d^4 y}{dx^4} \right] = \mathcal{L} \left[ \frac{W_0}{EI} \right] $$

$$ s^4 Y(s) - s^3 y(0) - s^2 y^\prime (0) - s y^{\prime \prime}(0) - y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{1}{s} $$

By applying the given boundary conditions, this equation reduces:

$$ s^4 Y(s) - s^2 y^\prime (0) - y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{1}{s} $$

$$ Y(s) = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{1}{s^5} + y^{\prime} (0) \frac{1}{s^2} + y^{\prime \prime \prime} (0) \frac{1}{s^4} $$

Now, take inverse Laplace Transform:

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} [Y(s)] = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{1}{s^5} + y^{\prime} (0) \frac{1}{s^2} + y^{\prime \prime \prime} (0) \frac{1}{s^4} \right] $$

$$ y(x) = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{x^4}{24} + y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) \frac{x^3}{6} + y^\prime(0)x $$

$$ y^{\prime \prime}(x) = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{x^2}{2} + y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) x $$

Then, apply other boundary conditions:

$$ y(L) = 0 = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{L^4}{24} + y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) \frac{L^3}{6} + y^\prime(0) L $$

$$ y^{\prime \prime}(L) = 0 = \frac{W_0}{EI} \frac{L^2}{2} + y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) L $$

which turns out to be

$$ y^{\prime \prime \prime}(0) = - \frac{W_0 L}{2EI} $$

Substitute into first boundary condition:

$$ y(L) = 0 = \frac{W_0 L^4}{24EI} - \frac{W_0 L^4}{12EI} + y^\prime(0) L $$

$$ y^\prime (0) = \frac{W_0 L^3}{24EI} $$

Combining all the terms:

$$ y(x) = \frac{W_0}{24EI} x^4 - \frac{W_0}{12EI} x^3 L + \frac{W_0}{24EI}x L^3 $$

Finally,

$$ y(x) = \frac{W_0}{24EI} \left( x^4 - 2L x^3 + L^3 x \right) $$

which is the deflection of simply supported beam at both sides with distributed loading.